# Hide go button SAPUi5

Tags: sapui5

Good Morning,

I an starting working with SAPUI5.

I want to hide a go button of a FilterBar (sap.ui.comp.filterbar.FilterBar)

I can use the method "hideGoButton()"?

How can I use it?

Thank you!

Comment: Hi, can you show us what you have tried?

Comment: var oFilterBar = new sap.ui.comp.filterbar.FilterBar({
   advancedMode: true,
   filterBarExpanded: false
   
  });

But I dont want to show the Go Button

Comment: Don't use `hideGoButton()`. It's a _protected_ method, i.e. not allowed to be used in application development. Better use `showGoOnFB` as mentioned in the answer below.

Answer (score 2):

There is a property on the FilterBar control called [`showGoOnFB`](https://ui5.sap.com/resources/sap/ui/comp/filterbar/FilterBar-dbg.js#:%7E:text=showGoOnFB,%7D).

```xml
<fb:FilterBar xmlns:fb="sap.ui.comp.filterbar" showGoOnFB="false">
```

If you want to hide the <kbd>Go</kbd> button dynamically or by using some sort of toggle event, like I assume you want to do based on your mention of `hideGoButton()` above, you can use an event handler similar to the one in the UI5 Explored sample:

[FilterBar samples](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/entity/sap.ui.comp.filterbar.FilterBar)

Check the code for sample 2. There is a function in there to hide the 'Filter' selector.

Comment: I use showGoOnFB: sap.ui.Device.system.phone, and get it

Thanks

Comment: @RubensP.P. Please consider accepting this answer to let others know that this question is resolved with this answer.